# Animate views constraint without animating other views

Tags: ios, swift, animation, autolayout, uikit

I'm trying to animate (up and down) all of the views in a viewController when the user moves from textField to textField where each textField has a keyboard with a different height and I'm using autolayout to position all of the views.

What I have is four`UITextFields` and three `UIButtons` using autolayout and which move up and down based on the different keyboards-height, my issue is that for some reason all of the views animate as soon as the viewController loads which is not what I want, I only want them to animate when the keyboard's height is different. The animation looks like it is animating all of the view's sizes and positions as soon as the viewController is loaded.

To drive the animation I have a main constraint (`constraintKeyboardHeight`) where all of the views are attached to for determining their vertical position (see image below).

FYI - Please note that I'm auto-focusing one of the textFields in the `viewDidLoad` method. I'm not sure if this has something to do with it.

Any idea? Is this normal behavior when animating views with constraints?

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     oneTextField.becomeFirstResponder()

     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(UserInputViewController.keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
}


func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
      if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {

      keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.height + 10

      UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, animations: {
        self.constraintKeyboardHeight.constant = keyboardHeight
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
      })
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `self.view.layoutIfNeeded` will trigger a layout update for everything contained in the view. If this includes subviews you don't want to animate, you should add all of the ones you *do* want to animate into a container subview. Constrain the container subview based on the keyboard, and call `layoutIfNeeded` on this subview only.

I'm a little confused by

> my issue is that for some reason all of the views animate as soon as the viewController loads which is not what I want, I only want them to animate when the keyboard's height is different

and I'm interpreting the issue as "all of the views animate" where you only want some of them. If the issue is more about the views animating immediately, that of course is going to happen since you set the first responder right when the view loads.

Edit: If you don't want to animate on the first load, you can add a property `var firstLoad = true` to your controller, then modify your keyboard will show function like so:

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo [UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
        keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.height + 10
        self.constraintKeyboardHeight.constant = keyboardHeight
        if firstLoad {
            view.layoutIfNeeded()
            firstLoad = false
        } else {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, animations: {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

You'll notice I moved the constraint constant line out of the animation block. You don't actually need this line in the animation block, just the `layoutIfNeeded` call.

Comment: @ Connor Neville - The issue is the views animating immediately, but apparently that's an expected behavior. If I understand this correctly `self.view.layoutIfNeeded` is updating all of the views directly in the main View from the viewController but why does the animation is applying to all of the views, position and size if I'm only specifying to animate one of the constraints? I would expect to animate all of the views but only up and down to adjust to the value of that constraint.

Comment: The animating immediately happens because the keyboard is appearing immediately, which sounds sensible to me, but if you don't want animation on the first load, you could set some sort of boolean flag for the first load. And yes, that's the expected behavior of layoutIfNeeded, because one constraint change can, and frequently does, change the layout of the entire view.

Comment: @ Connor Neville - Make sense now. One more question: How can I keep track of the loads? This could solve my issue since the animation work's as I expect after the first load. If this is too complicated I will go with adding the views to a single view as suggested in your answer. But I'm curious to see how that is done. Thanks.

Comment: Edited that into my comment.

Comment: You are awesome, Thanks a lot!

Comment: If I have a view with many subviews, and I want to animate just the dimensions of the view itself. What can I do? Moving the subviews to a containerView won't
 accomplish much if that containerView is also a part of that view.